# Animating the opening of a new activity containing list view on button click

Tags: android

I have a situation where I have a button which when clicked should expand the activity from the place of click and then the list items should stack on each other from top to bottom .please help me with the codw

Comment: try using this : http://developer.android.com/training/animation/index.html

Comment: @ParthAnjaria Sry that didn't help me